# sed multiple pattern and delete rest

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following file output which needs to be manipulated (cleaned up)

```
"2016-02-29;tracking;teamA;Name;45,0;7,0;315,0;659;"this is some free text";"911 Some Category";"again #pattern2 some free text #pattern1 #pattern3"
```

I need to filter and keep multiple pattern and clear the rest of a part of the line. The line should look like

```
"2016-02-29;tracking;teamA;Name;45,0;7,0;315,0;659;"this is some free text";"911 Some Category";"#pattern2 #pattern1 #pattern3"
```

So i need to manipulate just one part of the line and keep the rest.

I found ways to look for multiple patterns like

```
sed -e "s/#pattern1/#pattern1/g" -e "s/#pattern2/#pattern2/g"
```

and I found ways to delete everything but the pattern:

```
sed -e "s/.*#pattern1.*/#pattern1/g"
```

EDIT:
my solution at the moment:

I take the part of the line with awk (delimiter ;), egrep -o and paste it to the original. Looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
REGEXP="#(pattern1|pattern2|)"
paste $FILE <( cat $FILE |awk -F';' '{print$11}' | while read a; do a=$( echo $a | egrep -io "${REGEXP}"  | sort -u ) ; echo ";"${a//$'\n'/ } ; done )
```

Comment: Whilst it isn't difficult to write a sed script to do this, it would likely be a mess and there are far better alternatives.

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve]. As it stands it's pretty vague.

Comment: i think i misexplained. The problem is, that i did not paste the whole line and this led to misunderstanding. I add it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `sed` certainly can do the job, I would use `grep` (or `egrep` here):

```
egrep -o "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3" inputfile | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. The document has many lines and just a part of the whole line which i need to manipulate. For what you see here its just the awk -F';' '{print$14}' of one line.

Comment: This works but the output is spanned in multiple lines

Comment: @JackOverflow I don't understand. Why would it not work for multiple lines?

Comment: @JackOverflow Can you please edit your question and show more input and expected output?

Comment: i think i misexplained.

Answer (score 0):

You can negate matches with `!`, and you can also suppress auto-printing with the option `-n`. In that case, you need to explicitly print the lines you wish to keep with the `n` command.